# Convert floodfill open cv from c++ to python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am converting an opencv code from c++ to python and stucked somewhere near floodfill.

The c++ implemenation is

```
Mat floodFilled = cv::Mat::zeros(dilateGrad.rows+2, dilateGrad.cols+2, CV_8U);
floodFill(dilateGrad, floodFilled, cv::Point(0, 0), 0, 0, cv::Scalar(), cv::Scalar(), 4 + (255 << 8) + cv::FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY);
floodFilled = cv::Scalar::all(255) - floodFilled;
Mat temp;
floodFilled(Rect(1, 1, dilateGrad.cols-2, dilateGrad.rows-2)).copyTo(temp);
```

My python implementation

```
h, w = dilateGrad.shape[:2]
floodFilled =np.zeros((h+2,w+2),dtype = np.uint8)
cv2.floodFill(dilateGrad,floodFilled,(0,0),255,cv2.FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY)
floodFilled =  np.all(255) - floodFilled
floodFilled = cv2.rectangle(dilateGrad,1,1,(h-2,w-2),floodFilled,cv2.CV_8U)
```

I am new to opencv in python, anyone's help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: @GPPK i am not able to decode the last part of the floodfill i.e creating a scalar value for the floodfill and how the rectangle is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Rect` operator in the last line of C++ code is used to specify the ROI of `floodFilled` Mat and copy that ROI to `Mat temp`.

Similar behavior can be achieved in python code as follows:

```
temp = floodFilled[1:h-2, 1:w-2].copy()
```

As for the `Scalar` operator, you have to use python's tuple in place of `Scalar`. like `Scalar::all(255)` will be equal to `tuple([255] * NumberOfChannels)`. For you current case, the NumberOfChannels is **1**, so it will be equivalent to just **255**.

In place of empty `Scalar()`, just pass `None` as argument.

Your final code may look like this:

```
h, w = dilateGrad.shape[:2]
floodFilled = np.zeros((h+2,w+2), dtype = np.uint8)
cv2.floodFill(dilateGrad, floodFilled, (0,0), 255, None, None, cv2.FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY)
floodFilled =  (255) - floodFilled
temp = floodFilled[1:h-2, 1:w-2].copy()
```

**Just for info:**

The purpose of `cv2.rectangle` function is to draw a rectangle on the image.

`np.all` evaluates the list of binary conditions passed to it as an argument and returns True only if **all** of the conditions in the list evaluate to True.

Comment: thank you for the info but how can i use the scalar function of c++ in python.
And i cant get my cv2.floodfill correctly as i am getting a full black image.

Comment: Thank you properly explained